# How to access Twitter API resources using Twitter's Java library (twitter4j)

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I'm new to Twitters API and Twitter's twitter4j library. I've recently registered an app to be able to use Twitter's API.  Twitter has granted me consumer API keys (API key & API secret key), as well as an access token & access token secret.

The problem is, I've been trying to use twitter4j to authenticate into twitter (using the aforementioned keys), but when trying to access any of the APIs resources, I get an error saying I'm not allowed access due to a rate limit. But how can I possibly have reached a rate limit when I've never been able to query the api? :,(

This is what I'm attempting (with sensitive bits replaced by dummy values):

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App 
{

    private static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "FakeConsumerKey";
    private static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "FakeConsumerSecret";

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
        System.out.println("Making an authentication request to"
                + " retrieve the bearer token...");



        OAuth2Token token;
        token = getOAuth2Token();

        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();

        cb.setApplicationOnlyAuthEnabled(true);
        cb.setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
        cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);
        cb.setOAuth2TokenType(token.getTokenType());
        cb.setOAuth2AccessToken(token.getAccessToken());

        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();

        try {
            System.out.println("My screen name: " + twitter.getScreenName());
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

   }


    public static OAuth2Token getOAuth2Token()
    {
        OAuth2Token token = null;
        ConfigurationBuilder cb;

        cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setApplicationOnlyAuthEnabled(true);
        cb.setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
        cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);

        try
        {
            token = new TwitterFactory(cb.build())
                .getInstance().getOAuth2Token();

            System.out.println("token: " + token.getAccessToken());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Can't get OAuth2 token");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }

        return token;
    }

}
```

This is the error returned:

```
403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following).
message - Your credentials do not allow access to this resource
code - 220

Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=9a9caf7a or
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=bf94ba05
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[9a9caf7a-bf94ba05], statusCode=403, message=Your credentials do not allow access to this resource, code=220, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=4.0.6}
    at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:164)
    at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.request(HttpClientBase.java:57)
    at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.get(HttpClientBase.java:75)
    at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.fillInIDAndScreenName(TwitterBaseImpl.java:133)
    at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.fillInIDAndScreenName(TwitterBaseImpl.java:128)
    at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.getScreenName(TwitterBaseImpl.java:108)
    at com.vismark.social.twitter.TwitterAccountService.App.main(App.java:41)
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definition of getScreenName

"Returns authenticating user's screen name.
This method may internally call verifyCredentials() on the first invocation if
- this instance is authenticated by Basic and email address is supplied instead of screen name, or - this instance is authenticated by **OAuth**."

User-based authentication has to use OAuth 1.0a not OAuth 2. You need to get access tokens, follow this :
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/using-oauth

When you get your access tokens, just update your ConfigurationBuilder like this :

```
    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();

    cb.setApplicationOnlyAuthEnabled(false);
    cb.setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY)
    .setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET)
    .setOAuthAccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN)
    .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
```